# How can i get the flash player working

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am only looking to play some flash content on my page.
found this code on the web and just copied it into my codes and changed the file name. However the intellisense underlines part of the code in green and says "File 'swfobject.js' was not found" this is the code I copied below.

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type='text/javascript' src='swfobject.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var s1 = new SWFObject('cmsflash.swf','player', '400', '300', '9');
    s1.addParam('allowfullscreen', 'false');
    s1.addParam('allowscriptaccess', 'always');
    s1.addParam('flashvars', 'file=video.flv');
    s1.write('preview');
    </script>
<style type="text/css">
```

and it underlines only (swfobject.js) saying file not found. the file i wish to display is named cmsflash and is in the root directory probably ~/cmsflash.swf

where and what could be going wrong?

the block where the flash should display is declared as follows

```
 <table class="style2" style="height: 309px; width: 76%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p id='preview'>The player will show in this paragraph</p>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span class="style6">
<br />
```

Please Help

THIS IS THE NEW CODE AFTER I IMPORTED THE SWFOBJECT FOLDER.

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var s1 = new swfobject('~/cmsflash.swf','player', '400', '300', '9');
    s1.addParam('allowfullscreen', 'false');
    s1.addParam('allowscriptaccess', 'always');
    s1.addParam('flashvars', 'file=video.flv');
    s1.write('preview');
    </script>
```

I dont get any errors but the flash does not display at page load.

After several editing and flash still does not want to appear so i some more editing by adding a declaration in the master page(site.master) as shown below

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Prototype5.SiteMaster" %>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s1 = new SWFObject('cmsflash.swf', 'player', '400', '300', '9');
    s1.addParam('allowfullscreen', 'false');
    s1.addParam('allowscriptaccess', 'always');
    s1.addParam('flashvars', 'file=video.flv');        
    s1.write('preview');
    s1.write('preview1');
</script>
```

I also made a similar declaration in the child page just in case it was not supposed to be in the master page. so below is the code in the child page(default.aspx)

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Prototype5._Default" %>
```

var s1 = new SWFObject('cmsflash.swf', 'player', '400', '300', '9');
        s1.addParam('allowfullscreen', 'false');
        s1.addParam('allowscriptaccess', 'always');
        s1.addParam('flashvars', 'file=video.flv');
        s1.write('preview');
        s1.write('preview1');

This is the location where i asked for the flash to appear.

The player will show in this paragraph

I even suspected the flash file was probably not able to display in tables so i went further to declare a "div" as follows

```
<div id="preview1">The player will show in this paragraph
</div>
```

But flash still would not show...

Comment: @ Martheen - i just wanted to distinguish between the added changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you get `swfobject.js` from the same place you get this code which displaying your flash content? Also you may find `swfobject.js` here http://blog.deconcept.com/2007/02/28/swfobject-1-5-released/

Than put it in to your solution and check if path `src='swfobject.js'` in `<script type='text/javascript' src='swfobject.js'></script>` is correct.

Also you may drag and drop your `'swfobject.js'` file from solution to aspx and designer will add new `<script>` section with correct path.

UPDATE:

1) you need to say `var s1 = new SWFObject(...)` not `var s1 = new swfobject(...)`

2) `s1.write('preview');` it's mean "Place flash content to element with `Id = 'preview'`". So you need to place f.e.g `div` with `id='preview'` on your form. 
In your case if you don't have element `Id = 'preview'` there is nowhere to place your flash content.

```
<div id="preview"> 
  <strong>You need to upgrade your Flash Player</strong>   
</div>
```

Than it should work.

Comment: I think i got the path right this time after downloading, importing and dragging the swfobject.js file onto the form.i tried running again but the flash video does not appear...its only the text that the flash is supposed to replace. what is next to resolve to...?

Comment: Check path to your flash file, if it is correct try to remove ~ or ~/ from the beginning.

Comment: Yeah..i tried that but still wouldnt work. may be id go this way and see...(../flashfile) but i doubt it the cause...

Comment: Could it have somethign to do with the fact that am using a master page and am declaring the flash content in the subsequent page rather than the master page? i tried pasting the codes in the header of the master page but it didnt change the way it behavee. flash still wont display...any other work arounds?

Comment: @Selase see UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Tried everything and more but flash still does not appear. see my newly added edited codes.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the [swfobject.js](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) file on your site? That chunk of code doesn't actually play flash files, it just calls swfobject.js to generate the actual `<object>` and `<embed>` tags which will embed the flash file and play it.

Copy/pasting code which you do not even understand is a bad idea.

Comment: i have no idea where the swfobject.js is located. am only developing on my local laptop. how am i supposed to include it?

Comment: Get a copy from that url, put in your site somewhere, and point that ASP code at it. Just like you'd include an image or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

swfobject.js is a javascript library you have to include on your page via a script tag. Is the path to swfobject.js correct in your tag?

Comment: Am not sure i have the javascript library. ho do i know if i do and if i dont have it how do i add it?